# Fading in amcharts (startAlpha without startEffect)

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to get charts to fade in without having them bounce in, or come in elastically, etc.

From the docs, it says that elastic is the default animation type. I tried blank, or "none". Those crash amcharts.

See the following fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tegnu71s/

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
"type": "pie",
"theme": "light",
 startDuration:"10",
 startEffect:"elastic",
 startAlpha:0,
"dataProvider": [ {
"country": "Lithuania",
"litres": 501.9
 }, {
"country": "Czech Republic",
"litres": 301.9
} ],
"valueField": "litres",
"titleField": "country",
 "balloon":{
 "fixedPosition":true
},
"export": {
  "enabled": true
}
} );
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly identified the `startAlpha` parameter. It will make the slices fade in.

Now, to just disable the bounce effect, set [`startRadius`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#startRadius) to zero:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "startDuration": 10,
  "startRadius": 0,
  "startAlpha": 0,
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  }],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
  "balloon": {
    "fixedPosition": true
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 250px;"></div>
```

If you want the slices fade in all at once as opposed to one by one, set [`sequencedAnimation: true`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#sequencedAnimation)

Comment: Is there a similar solution for serial charts?

Comment: Only using CSS: https://www.amcharts.com/tips/using-css-animation-apply-effects-chart-elements/